# Резиновый трёхколоночный макет

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

уважаемые html разработчики. Такой вопрос, как написать главную страницу сайта при использовании резинового трехколонного макета, таким образом что бы расстояние от границы монитора до моего макета было константой на всех мониторах.И да, подскажите что изучить что бы и на мобильных устройствах страничка смотрелась адекватно. Благодарю за внимание. Rookie.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону bootstrap, на оф сайте есть огромная куча примеров его использования, может и для себя что-то выберете. Так же, на мой взгляд, очень не плохо он смотрится на мобильных устройствах.

Comment: Выше правильный совет.
Мой совет глянуть:
bootstrap
Foundation
UIKit

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap. 
классы "col-sm-4, col-md-4, col-lg-4" каждому из трёх блоков.